# Receive only a handful of UDP packets after a redir. (Android Emulator)

Tags: java, android, udp, emulation

I wrote a desktop java program to talk to the server I'm trying to reach and got it working. I can send and receive UDP packets. I know what to port what I've done to android. I've been messing around with the Android Emulator for a couple days and ran into an issue with receiving UDP packets. If I start my app, make the connection to the server, then redir the port I'm using, I get ~130 packets that come in and then nothing ... I used WireShark to make sure the server was still sending packets and it is. Is there something like [IP Flood Detection](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/283600-udp-connection-problem/) on the Android's Emulator?

EDIT:

spelling

- The server is connected to a switch that my dev computer is connected to.
- The server is responding to my packets that I send from the desktop app.
- The server is sending the packets to the dev comupters IP address.
- The redir command I'm using is "redir add udp:port:port"
- When I issue the redir command, I get the ~130 packets with a from address of "10.0.2.2"
- I've tried "adb forward udp:port udp:port" and get "cannot bind to socket"
- The server's IP from outside the emulator is "10.10.0.100"

EDIT

- The server is not on the emulator or another android device

Comment: Can you add more detail? Is the server in your local network, is the server receiving the device packets, to which address is the server sending the packets, what REDIR command parameters did you use?

Comment: The server is connected to a switch that my dev computer is connected to. The server is responding to my packets  that I send from the desktop app. The server is sending the packets to the dev comupters IP address. The redir command I'm using is "redir add udp:port:port".

Comment: With that setup you shoudn't receive any UDP packet in the device, because is missing the carrier from your dev computer IP address to the dev computer loopback address. Are you sure that you receive any UDP packet comming from the server in the device?

Comment: [PART 1] Thanks for your help. The server outside the emulator and dev computer is recieving the packets. The server is setup to turn on an LED once the correct byte is set in the packet. The LED can be turned on and of from the emulator without issue. I can read the custom information from the UDP packets sent to the emulator only after I start talking to the server and then issue the "redir add udp:port:port" command.

Comment: [PART 2] So I am sure that the packets I'm seeing after the redir jiggling is from the server and intact. Wireshark shows that the server is sending a constant stream of UDP packets to the dev computer so there should be more then ~130 packets coming in.

Comment: I'm still missing something... Why are you adding the REDIR after you connect to the server and not before?

Comment: I started the AVD, redir the port, launched the app with eclipse, connected to the server, received 56 packets, and nothing else. The server is constantly sending out a status packet.

Comment: I've posted an answer with some detailed information on how to solve it. I hope :-) Let me know if not,

Answer (score 1):

I did a test with similar setup and got the same behaviour.

Sending a UDP packet per second after aprox. 130 packets the receiver running in the emulator stop receiving packets, and I confirm that the packets kept being sent.

I've made the test above in emulator using SDK 10 and SDK 15, both running in Intel Accelerated Execution Manager.

It looks like a bug in the emulator redirection functionality, or as you suggest, some type of network flood prevention.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got sudppipe running and can see the packets it's redirecting. I haven't seen any packets inside the app. redir won't bind to the socket because it's already in use. I think I might have to fiddle with the sudppipe settings. I'm using "sudppipe -x  127.0.0.1 port port".

Comment: I've made some testing and it looks like that sudppipe is always binding to the localhost (127.0.0.1) for input, even if you specify the -b option. It seems to work if you use different ports for in and out. I'm going to edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I see :
'code' serverADDR:severOutputPort -> 127.0.0.1:deviceInputPort
HEX VALUES OF PACKET'code' 

But nothing in the app... So the emulator is listening to the localhost's loopback address? It seems like it's listening somewhere else. I'll keep hacking at it till I get results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you change the socket input port in the device to the new value used in sudppipe? I've some code writen and working using this. I'll have a look and I'll come back to you.

Comment: I changed the socket port to match the new deviceInputPort. I can see through the sudppipe cmd that packets are being moved to the 127.0.0.1:deviceInputPort but I'm not seeing anything in the app... Redir modifies the virtual router of the emulator Right? I only have seen packets in the app when I redir. sudppipe modifies where packets are going on my localhost right? Does that mean the virtual router isn't linked/listening to the localhost?

Comment: Sorry, but I mislead you with my initial answer. You only need to pipe incomming TCP connections. I've made a test replicating your architecture and got the same behaviour. I've never noticed it before, as the UDP was only used to share IP (a couple of packets), and then I reverted to TCP. I adjusted the answer accordingly, to avoid mislead others.

Comment: GAHHH!! :/ Thanks for confirming this :) Do I mark your answer as correct then?

Comment: You could upvote it for being usefull, and wait for a while to see if someone else comes with a solution. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I bought a Nexus 7, ran this app I've been working on and can receive 3000+ packets. Looks like its something with the emulator.